How to call column name when it is a timestamp in python?
I am getting a keyerror when trying to call my column whose header is a timestamp, how do I overcome this?
my dataset is
  date      10:05:00  
2022-12-01  90.00286   
2022-12-02  88.97760   
2022-12-05  89.29583  
2022-12-06  90.30789  
2022-12-07  91.44738  


df['10:05:00'] = df['10:05:00'].sum()

but getting a keyerror
KeyError: '10:05:00'

If your column really is a timestamp object, is should show a date, please provide a [mre]

Why don't you simply rename that column so that you can call it?

Just rename the column , later also it will be very painful to work with

You can try using a datetime.time object as a key in your dataframe, or you can convert your column names to strings.
# recreating the dataframe here

import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

df = pd.DataFrame({
 'date': [
  '2022-12-01',
  '2022-12-02',
  '2022-12-05',
  '2022-12-06',
  '2022-12-07'],
 dt.time(10, 5, 0): [
  90.00286,
  88.9776,
  89.29583,
  90.30789,
  91.44738]
})

df
# returns:
         date  10:05:00
0  2022-12-01  90.00286
1  2022-12-02  88.97760
2  2022-12-05  89.29583
3  2022-12-06  90.30789
4  2022-12-07  91.44738

To access the first column you can use:
df[dt.time(10,5,0)].sum()
# returns:
450.03156

Or you can convert the column names to strings:
df.columns = [str(c) for c in df.columns]
df['10:05:00'].sum()
# returns:
450.03156


Here is how to rename your column and be able to call it:
df = pd.DataFrame(

    {"date":["2022-12-1","2022-12-2","2022-12-5","2022-12-6","2022-12-7"],
     "10:05:00":[90.2568,80.1253,75.3687,68.4522,71.0234]}
)

# rename column to 'Values'
df.rename(columns={"10:05:00":"Values"},inplace=True)

print(df)

         date    Values
0   2022-12-1   90.2568
1   2022-12-2   80.1253
2   2022-12-5   75.3687
3   2022-12-6   68.4522
4   2022-12-7   71.0234
    

# call column
df["Values"] = df["Values"].sum()


.loc can access columns with non-standard names
df.loc[:, '10:05:00'] = df['10:05:00'].sum()

or you can use raw string method
df[r'10:05:00'] = df[r'10:05:00'].sum()

highly recommend you to Just Rename the column

This does not solve the problem because the column name/key is not a string.

then you can map it  df.columns = df.columns.map(str)  after finding out the type of column and then after map recheck the type again and use
